# tortoise svn repository multiple files in folder with different revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, revision

I have created a new repository for example named excel_files with several files
I want that each file has a own revision number.
For example how it now:A.xls (Rev 4);B.xls (Rev 7)
when i change A.xls and commit, the revision of A.xls is 8
But I want that it is 5.

Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in one repository.

You can place each file into separate repository or write more details about your use case